# show loading spinner in the Jquery popup

Tags: jquery, iframe, progress-bar, bpopup

I am using jquery popup that loads a external page inside an Iframe.

Now I want to show loading spinner or loading bar image and hide the external page/iframe while its working,so user only sees the spinner.

can it be done,if yes how.please help me.

Here is the code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("a#em4c").bind("click", function () {
            $("#popup2").bPopup({ content: 'iframe', contentContainer: '#pContent', loadUrl: "http://site.com" });
            return false
        });

    });
</script>
```

html Part

```
<p><a id="em4c"><strong>POP ME</strong>: Simple jquery popup that loads a page   inside an iframe</a></div>
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might This would be helpful for you

```
<form>
Your input elements 
</form>
<div id="dialog1" title="Waiting" style="display:none">
<img src="/spinning.gif" border="0" align="left" hspace="12"/> Place all your text here   
<iframe id="iframe1" src="" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
Place all your Text 
</div>
```

write this in document.ready

```
$("#dialog1").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 150,
                weight: 50,
                resizable: false,   
                modal: true 
            });
```

//On click of the Element You can do in this way

```
$("a#em4c").bind("click", function () {
        $('#dialog1').removeAttr('style');
        $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
            var url ="some.php";
            $('#iframe1').attr('src',url);
    })
```

On click Of the Element it will Open the Spinning Image after That it opens some.php in the 
iframe. Is this you were expecting?

Comment: +1 for this! @Priya, You must add jquery ui css and js to your page for it to work and it's a little complex the first time you do it:  1) http://jqueryui.com/download - go here and deselect all boxes except for, 'Dialog' then click [Download]. 2) Add the css, js, and images to your site. 3) import the css in the <head> of your page before any js imports, and import the jquery ui js file in the <head> of your page immediately AFTER your jquery js import. Should work after that.

Comment: Thanks I have done all that but didn't work...anyway i figured a different way..thanks for help both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jQuery plugin. [Here are a few variations of a jQuery Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) (popup). I would use this [SimpleModal jQuery plugin at ericmmartin.com](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/). It says, "Loading" as the content loads and I'm sure this can be overridden with a loading spinner graphic.

Comment: thanks,but then how do i hide the iframe while its working in the background.

Comment: It does not hide it. There are other way to do this.. such as loading everything in to a hidden div, then when the content is loaded you can add it to a modal popup.